How many $G$ of accelaration do we experience when we come to a flat surface from a slope?
I was recently riding a bicycle when I realised that when I went onto a flat road from a short but steep slope, I felt something weird in my body as if I was expereiencing some difference in the gravity acting on me. 
Also,is there a generalized formulae to calculate the accelaration of gravity on us where the slope has an angle of θ and length of s and we are moving with velocity v.

The limiting case is when you have a sharp transition from a ramp to flat.

Before you encounter the transition you feel the ground reaction $W \cos \theta$ which is slightly less than the weight $W$ since you are on a slope. After the transition, you feel 100% of your weight.
When you encounter the transition, there is going to be a short time period where you experience weightlessness as you do a tiny jump until you came to rest on the flat surface.

When you encounter the transition, there is going to be a short time period where you experience weightlessness as you do a tiny jump until you came to rest on the flat surface. :Is "weightlessness" accurate?

"weightlessness" means you will be in free fall. Gravity still applies, but there will be nothing holding you place and therefore you won't feel the effects of gravity. @SambhavKhandelwal

As you go from the slop onto the flat you (and the bike) are accelerating. Even though your speed may be constant, the direction of your velocity is changing - it is rotating through an angle $\theta$. This means that your acceleration has a downwards component. As a result, the upwards force which the bike exerts on you (which is usually equal to your weight) is briefly reduced. To you this feels as if you have become briefly lighter - similar to how you feel in a lift that is accelerating downwards.
The amount of the acceleration does not depend on the length of the slope, but it does depend on how abruptly the slope changes into the flat. An abrupt change will result in a higher acceleration (and so a greater feeling of lightness) than a gradual change.

Thanks for the answer. But, how can I calculate the amount of $G$ force on me. I did understand that I feel it to be less than 1. But how much is it? And at which angle would I completely feel weightless(almost)?

@SambhavKhandelwal As I said, the size of the effect depends on the exact shape of the transition between the slope and the flat. If it is a very abrupt transition and you are going fast enough then you will feel completely weightless since the bike will lose contact with the ground at the top of the slope.

I get your point but we already know how abruptly the slope transitions as in the diagram. It is 180 - θ.

@SambhavKhandelwal We need to know the shape of the transition. Is it a sharp corner ? Is it a smooth curve - and if so, what is the shape of the curve ? If you know the shape of the transition and the speed of the bike then you can in principle work out the forces on the bike, but in practice the calculation may be complex.

It is a smooth curve. The shape of the curve can be a smooth parabola. ( I dont know if I''m correctly mentioning the type of curve as I dont know how do I define the corner radius of the curve and etc...)

We also need to know a bunch of geometry on the bike.  For example, the distance between the wheels will change the path you take.  Also, different parts of your body may experience different forces because the body is springy.  As gandalf points out, in principle you could come up with an equation, but in practice there's a lot of details we would need to fill in first.
